# NSLog - How to print object name?

Tags: ios, nslog, objectname

Consider,

```
NSString *myString = @"Welcome";

NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```

will print `Welcome` in console.

Can I print the string like "`myString: Welcome`"?

I mean, can I get the object name("`myString`") along with object value("`Welcome`")?

Comment: You can do like..    NSLog(@"myString : %@",myString);

Comment: But he would to print his variable name

Comment: @confused if you satisfied with my answer then please mark it as a accepted.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I knew to print like NSLog(@"myString : %@",myString); I want to print the object name without typing its name.

Comment: no.. i have posted my answer you can see that.

Comment: Marked as the right answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use the following code:**

```
#define stringVariable(x) NSLog( @"%s:%@",#x, x) 

NSString *myString=@"Welcome";

stringVariable(myString);
```

**Note:** The general principle is that when you put a # in front of an argument within the body of a #define, the preprocessor replaces it with a C string of the exact expression passed to the macro. When you pass a variable name, you'll get that name.

Comment: This is correct, but I'd advise to use a different macro name. `stringVariable` might conflict with existing variable names. And since it is a macro, it might cause tricky and not obvious errors. Usually, all-uppercase is used for macros. In conjunction with a prefix, it should be more or less safe. Something like `CF_LOG_OBJECT_VARIABLE(x)`. You don't have to type it anyway. Viva la autocomplete :)

Comment: @FreeNickname Thanks for suggestion next time sure i will do that.

Comment: @AshokLondhe Just for the clarification. I tried the above code and its worked. But when I try this without defining it as macro, means I tried "NSLog( @"%s:%@",#myString, myString) " and it throws an error "Expected expression". Any idea?

Comment: Yes.. Because of that i have declare that as a macro. i thing only solution to it is macro.