# Customized NSLog to print all type of objects

Tags: ios, macros, custom-controls, parameter-passing, nslog

I'm trying to extend NSLog that can print any type of object. Means, my custom class gets the value that need to be printed from the user and checks its class type and then it will print as desired format.

Consider my extended class name is, `MyLog` (So it contains `MyLog.h` and `MyLog.m`)

**MyLog.h:**

```
void MyLog (id objectValue);
```

**MyLog.m:**

```
#import "MyLog.h"

void MyLog (id objectValue)
{
    if ([objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",objectValue); //Same for NSArray, NSDictionary, NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary
    }

    else if ([objectValue isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:objectValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

So, if I include this class (`MyLog.h`) in prefix file, I can call the below method from any class to simply print the given object.

```
MyLog(valueOfObject);
```

**Problems:**

- The `CGRect`, `CGpoint`, `CGSize` related things (which are not an object) can not be passed as `id` to `MyLog()` function.
- I tried to print the object name along with its value for more readability. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893406/nslog-how-to-print-object-name).

For example,

```
NSString *myString = @"Welcome";

MyLog(myString);
```

This will print `myString: Welcome` instead of just printing `Welcome`.

I can achieve this my defining a preprocessor like

```
#define MYLOG(x) NSLog( @"%s:%@",#x, x)
```

So, I tried to customize it in the following way

```
#define MYLOG(x) NSLog(@"%s:%@",#x, MyLog(x))
```

But it throws "`Argument type 'void' is incomplete`" error.

**Questions:**

- How can I pass non objects as id to a function?
- How can I call a function within a preprocessor macro?

Help needed!! Just Confused!!

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `-(NSString*)description` you can print any object in NSLog with `NSLog(@"%@", myObject)`.

So just add `-(NSString*)description` in the classes of objects that you want to print out, and in them just return the `NSString` value that you think is relevant for that object.

Comment: Is this answer for my question 1?

Comment: This isn't directly an answer to your question, but a suggestion on how to do it easier. There is no need to create your own NSLog. If you want, I can show you how to write code for your exact function, but I really advise against it since you already have a perfect solution built in.

Comment: When you pass an object into NSLog, the `description` method is called. So all you need to do is make sure you implement it in your class.