# how can I print name of object in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I print name of objects in Xcode? I am getting address of objects. Instead, I want names. Output is coming the address of boxes instead. How to get name of the boxes box 1 box 2?

[image]

Comment: do you mean the class name ?

Comment: when you pass an object b, you want the name b to print ?

Comment: pls read the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893406/nslog-how-to-print-object-name

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That doesn't work here because the logging is being done in a location that doesn't reference the original variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Each `Box` instance has no concept of the name of the variable used elsewhere to point to it. In fact, any number of different variables can reference the same `Box` instance so it makes no sense to attempt to print the variable name.

If you really want a name, add a `name` property to your `Box` class.

And the best way to get sane output when logging a class instance, override the `description` method.

Add this to your `Box` class in the .m file:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Box: h:%f x w:%f x l:%f", _height, _width, _length];
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, I want to know, if  this isn't enough or not.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893406/nslog-how-to-print-object-name ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Not in this case because there is no reference to the original variable in the code doing the logging.